# How old were Minato and Kushina when they died in Naruto?

Tags: naruto

I've been trying to find out their age when they died. I'm not really sure but I think they were in their twenties.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both Minato and Kushina died at the age of 24.

Minato's birthday is estimated to be around the 1st of January/31st of December. Following this up using the timeline as provided on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TimeLine/comments/3lh69h/naruto_timeline/)

- Minato enters the academy at the age of 9, Kushina at the age of 8
- Minato became a Genin at 10, under Jiraiya's lead
- Kushina is abducted at the age of 13-14, and saved by Minato at around the same age
- The 3th Shinobi war starts, where Minato is around the age of 20.
- The Kannabi Bridge is destroyed by Minato Namikaze at the age of 23, shortly followed by the end of the war, where he also became the Yondaime
- Minato defeats Obito, seals Yin Kurama in his body and Yang Kurama in Naruto
- Minato dies at roughly at the age of 24, Kushina Uzumaki dies at age 24

These ages are based upon the mentioned dates mentioned through out the series, and the [Naruto Wiki timeline](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/User:Seelentau/NewTimeline).